# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'xxxxx' in undefined in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, cdn

I'm trying to create a modal form that will add a record.  I am able to display the default values from data but as soon as I try to modify the field, I get the following error whenever I try to type changes to the input box.

> ```
> *vue.min.js:6 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'fullname' in undefined
>     at a.ke [as $set] (vue.min.js:6)
>     at input (eval at Ya (vue.min.js:1), <anonymous>:3:2182)
>     at He (vue.min.js:6)
>     at HTMLInputElement.n (vue.min.js:6)
>     at HTMLInputElement.Yr.o._wrapper (vue.min.js:6)*
> ```

In given Below I added the code of the component I'm trying to create:
Any help, please.

```js
var bus = new Vue();

Vue.component('leagues_add', {

 props: {
   show: Boolean,
   is_admin: Boolean,
   
  },

 data: function () {
   return {
    newLeague: {"fullname":"a", "notes":"b", "group_image_path": "c"} // remember to always enclose the fieldnames in doublequotes
   }
  },

 methods: {
       closeModal() {
       this.show = false;
    },
    showModal() {
       this.show = true;
    },
    addLeague() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = this.toFormData(this.newLeague);

    axios.get("http://"+ window.location.hostname +"/db/leagues/index.php?action=create").then(function(response){

    if (response.data.error) {
     app.errorMessage = response.data.message;
    } else {
     app.leagues = response.data.leagues;
    }

       });
    },
    toFormData(obj) {
     var fd = new FormData();
     for (var i in obj) {
      fd.append(i, obj[i]);
     }
     return fd;
    },

   }
 ,
 template:  
 `
 <!-- Add new Leage -->

 <div> 
        <div class="text-center pb-3" >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-success text-white" @click="showModal"><b class="" style="">Add League</b></button>
 </div>

 <transition name="modal"> 
  <div id="overlay" v-show="this.show">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Add League</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" @click="closeModal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <form action="#" method="POST">
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" v-model="this.newLeague.fullname" class="form-control form-control-md" placeholder="Name of League">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <textarea v-model="this.newLeague.notes" rows="3" cols="100%" name="notes" class="form-control form-control-md" placeholder="Describe this league">
        </textarea>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group form-inline ">
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
         <input type="url" v-model="this.newLeague.group_image_path" class="col-5 pull-left form-control form-control-md" placeholder="Image URL">
            &nbsp;
            <button class="col-4 btn btn-primary btn-md">Image</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-md" @click="closeModal();addLeague();">Add this league</button>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>   
  </div>
 </transition>
<div>
 
 `

});
```

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">LEAGUES SECTION</div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2">      
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <leagues_add :show="true" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a full example on jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
v-model="this.newLeague.fullname"
```

You cannot use `this.` with `v-model`. Instead it should be:

```
v-model="newLeague.fullname"
```

You should also remove all other references to `this` within your template. In many cases they are harmless but sometimes, such as with `v-model`, they will cause problems.

Complete examples below. Note how the first input does not function correctly when editing the text.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  
  data () {
    return { newLeague: { fullname: 'League 1' } }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  
  data () {
    return { newLeague: { fullname: 'League 1' } }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app1">
  <input type="text" v-model="this.newLeague.fullname">
  {{ newLeague.fullname }}
</div>

<div id="app2">
  <input type="text" v-model="newLeague.fullname">
  {{ newLeague.fullname }}
</div>
```

Comment: using **this** is simply needless but if you use **this** it still works.

Comment: @Anatoly Not true. In some scenarios it can cause a failure. Examples include `v-model`, inside `v-on` as well as inside scoped slots.

Comment: I talk about this scenario and not about all possible ones.

Comment: @Anatoly I have added a runnable example to my answer that demonstrates that using `this.` causes the exact error message described by the OP when using `v-model` on an `<input>`.

Comment: Let me know if im doing this wrong.  I declared the section **data: function () {...** within the component.  Should it be declared outside of the component instead like the example of @skirtle?  Is there a way for it to be correctly declared from within the component?

Comment: @RockyCastaneda The `data` function on your component looks fine to me. My examples are there purely to illustrate what happens when you prefix the `v-model` value with `this.`. The first example will give the same console error you reported in the question. The second example omits the `this.` and does not cause an error. There may be other problems with your code but that specific error message will be because of the `this.` in your `v-model` attribute.

Comment: I tried removing the this. in my v-model and I still get the same error: 
**vue.min.js:6 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'fullname' in undefined
    at a.ke [as $set] (vue.min.js:6)
    at input (eval at Ya (vue.min.js:6), <anonymous>:3:1203)
    at He (vue.min.js:6)
    at HTMLInputElement.n (vue.min.js:6)
    at HTMLInputElement.Yr.o._wrapper (vue.min.js:6)**

Answer (score 0):

I followed the way @skirtle wrote the data section and it worked.

My original syntax was:

```
data: function () {
            return {
                newLeague: {"fullname":"a", "notes":"b", "group_image_path": "c"}           }
        }
```

**to**

```
data () {
    return { newLeague: { fullname: 'League 1' } }
  }
```